# Incrementing td field of tr via id

Tags: jquery

Want to increment last `td` field in a doubleclicked `tr` but can't seem to get it to work.
`Td`'s are dynamically added.

```
$("#addnewitem").click(function () {
$item = $("#selectitem").val();
if ($item == "No selection") {
    alert("No selection");
} else {
    $("#tabelbody").append("<tr id=" + $item + "><td></td><td>" + $item + "</td>"
    + "<td>1</td>" /*WANT TO INCREMENT THIS TD'S VALUE*/
    +"</tr>");
}
 });
 $("#tabel").on('dblclick','tr',function(){
var trid = $(this).attr('id'); // table row ID 
alert(trid);

});
```

Comment: Increment how? It seems you are using a non-numerical value as ID.

Comment: You mean something like `$item + 1`?

Comment: Can you please translate for us this part: *Want to increment last td field in a doubleclicked tr*

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$("#tabel").on('dblclick', 'tr', function(){
    var t=$(this).find("td:last");
    t.text( parseInt(t.text(), 10) + 1);
});
```

Comment: `$(this).attr('id')` === `this.id` (simplicity sake)

Comment: and would that not be parseInt(t.text(),10)++

Comment: @mplungjan yes you are right otherwise its string concatenation. just monday morning ...

Comment: @mplungjan just copied from question. Yes we don't need to get that as we are not using it anywhere. Thanks for edit.

Answer (score 1):

You should do:

```
$("#tabel").on('dblclick','tr',function(){
   var $tr = $(this);    //Get tr
   var $td = $tr.find("td:last");  //Get last td
   var oldValue = parseInt($td.text(), 10);   //Get previous value
   $td.text(oldValue + 1);    //Update value
});
```

I did it in several steps so you can understand it better

Comment: Use radix parameter while handling with `parseInt`

Comment: Yep, we don't know his browser support. Edited

Comment: Quit double-signing your posts please.